# Using Mercurial with TFS-like work item tracking

Tags: mercurial, tfs, alm

Does Mercurial offer any type of extensions that offer functionality similar to TFS's work items that when you check in changes that you can associate them to features/defects?

If there isn't much (or any) support for this, how do you handle ALM using Mercurial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you may be looking for is called a `distributed bugtracker`. There is a number of those available on top of that or another dvcs.
I've come across a couple of links:

1. [Bugs Everywhere](http://bugseverywhere.org)
2. [DisTract](http://lwn.net/Articles/231852/)
3. [Distributed bug tracking](http://lwn.net/Articles/281849/)

Comment: A distributed bugtracker would definitely be the corresponding piece to a DVCS, of course it'd be great if both Bugs Everywhere and DisTract's website would be working at the moment so I could actually have an idea of what their product looks like / does.

Answer (score 2):

there is the [Bugzilla extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugzillaExtension) but this isn't quite what you want out of the box i think? it may be a good starting point though if you want to write your own extension/[hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) to do exactly what you want

if you want to pay money cash then there is [fogbugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) and [kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/Kiln/)

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best shot here is so far to add it yourself by using the hooks feature in Mercurial.

I've been looking at this for our in-house installation of TargetProcess. You can find more at this post which I've found in my own search for this: http://mattadamson.blogspot.com/2009/11/building-mercurial-external-hook-to.html

This should be feasible as long as your system for handling features/defects offer an API for manipulating its data.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it out from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems) wikipedia, and go to "Revision Control System Integration" section which is at the end of the wiki.

I think your question should be what issue tracking systems can integrate with mercurial, not the way around since mercurial is just a source control system. Famous free issue tracking system like BugTracker.NET, Bugzilla, Redmine, Trac are all supporting mercurial integration, which means you can integrate your mercurial repository with them to keep track of your changes etc.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this project : http://hgtfshook.codeplex.com/documentation

Am about to try it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Artemis](http://www.mrzv.org/software/artemis/) extension which is a lightweight issue tracking that handles each issue as an email thread, storing them in the same repository.  It's easy to install, just download it and add one line to your `.hgrc` file.  To add or modify an issue, just type `hg iadd`. I personally found it easy and simple to use. It's missing a web interface, though.